# Problema com a definição de rotas Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

Estou enfrentando um problema com Laravel (5.4.36) ao definir um novo controler para a rota do meu localhost.

Ao definir o controller a ser usando pela rota:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\EventController;

Route::get('/', [EventController::class, 'index']);
```

E este é o controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class EventController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
        $nome = 'Pedro';
        $idade = '21';
    
        $arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
        $nomes = ["Matheus", "João", "Maria"];
    
        return view('welcome', 
        ['nome' => $nome,
        'idade' => $idade, 
        'profissao' => "Progamador",
        'arr' => $arr,
        'nomes' => $nomes
        ]);
    
    }
}
```

Quando acesso o localhost, surge o seguinte erro na página:

> ReflectionFunction::__construct() expects parameter 1 to be string,
> array given
>
> in RouteSignatureParameters.php line 22.

O que pode ser ?

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score -4):

tente assim

```
Route::get('/', 'EventController@index');
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).